# How to set custom headerlink?

Tags: python-sphinx

How I can customize headerlink in sphinx?

```
.. page.html

page
====

My header
______
```

`My header` resolve to link `http://example.com/page.html#my-header`

How to get `http://example.com/page.html#my-custom-headerlink` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reference a link with the following format:

```
page
====

`My Header <http://example.com/page.html#my-custom-headerlink>`_
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

or

```
`My Header <page.html#my-custom-headerlink>`_
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

You can also reference it like:

```
`my-header`_
--------------

.. _my-header: http://example.com/page.html#my-custom-headerlink
```

Using raw html you can have more control including control over the headerlink, however you lose it rendering in the toc.

```
.. raw:: html

    <div class="section" id="my-custom-headerlink">
    <h2><a class="reference external" href="index.html#my-custom-headerlink">My Header</a>
    <a class="headerlink" href="#my-custom-headerlink" title="Permalink to this headline">¶</a></h2>
    </div>
```

Comment: thx you for help me again. That works, but not as I expected. I need change `headerlink` this link appear when mouse move over header(right from the header). Your examples also does not change link in the `toctree`. Is that even possible?

Comment: Thats promblem for me, because I use russian text and all anchors links resolve like `#id3`. And direct links will broken if I'll insert new header.

Comment: I see your problem. The closest I can get to a solution with out custom sphinx code is using the raw directive to create a section, see my edit above. However, you lose it in the TOC completely then.

Comment: Thanks Cole, but I can't make each header as your workaround. It's horrible.